# Impedir enviar HTML en "User Submission Form" (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin, textarea

Estoy tratando de averiguar cómo hacer que en el textarea del plugin User Submission Form para Wordpress, no sea posible enviar marcado HTML, que se envíe puro texto plano.

He localizado esta parte del submission-form.php

```
<?php $usp_rte_settings = array(
                'wpautop'          => false,  // enable rich text editor
                'media_buttons'    => true,  // enable add media button
                'textarea_name'    => 'user-submitted-content', // name
                'textarea_rows'    => '10',  // number of textarea rows
                'tabindex'         => '',    // tabindex
                'editor_css'       => '',    // extra CSS
                'editor_class'     => 'usp-rich-textarea', // class
                'teeny'            => false, // output minimal editor config
                'dfw'              => false, // replace fullscreen with DFW
                'tinymce'          => false,  // enable TinyMCE
                'quicktags'        => false,  // enable quicktags
                'drag_drop_upload' => false,  // enable drag-drop
            );
            $usp_rte_settings = apply_filters('usp_editor_settings', $usp_rte_settings);
            $usp_editor_content = apply_filters('usp_editor_content', '');
            wp_editor($usp_editor_content, 'uspcontent', $usp_rte_settings); ?>
            
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            
        <label for="user-submitted-content"><?php esc_html_e('Post Content', 'usp'); ?></label>
        <textarea id="user-submitted-content" name="user-submitted-content" rows="10" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Post Content', 'usp'); ?>"<?php if (usp_check_required('usp_content')) echo $usp_required; ?> class="usp-textarea"></textarea>
        <?php } ?>
```

Pero quizás hay que integrar una función en functions.php similar a la de impedir HTML en comentarios:

```
function remove_html($comment) {
    return strip_tags($comment, '<strong><b><em><p>');
}
add_filter('get_comment_text', 'remove_html');
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

[submission-form.php](https://www.sendspace.com/file/z8qhbw)